# Iperf3 keeps hanging when running UDP test

Tags: linux-networking, python, udp, iperf

I wrote a Python program that runs `iperf3` in a for loop with different datagram sizes. I am using Python's `subprocess.call` function to run `iperf3` like this:

```
 iperf3 -u -c 185.82.21.60 -b 100M -t 5 -l <datagram size>
```

My datagram size starts with 1000 and increases by 100 after each iteration and should run until it reaches a size of 2000. Every time I am running my program, iperf3 keeps hanging after the 6th time and starts using 100% of one of my CPUs.
After this I cannot use iperf3 anymore until I kill the running client process and restart the iper3 server.

Here is a picture to illustrate my problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that my problem is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/237). The solution seems to be to update the ESX hosts's drivers.